# How to append active color to the li element on filtering?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to append active class for the li element based on filtering in Angular, I  tried with ng-class but I am not getting.

Here is my HTML code:

```
 <div class="input-group dropdown" style="margin-top:50px;margin-
 left:100px;">
   <input type="text"  class="form-control" ng-model="input.val" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-describedby="basic-addon2" ng-change="fnAutocompleteQuestion(input.val)"  >
       <div class="dropdown-menu width-menu">
           <ul style="width: 225px; height: auto; overflow: auto; list-style-type: none;margin-left: -30px;">
               <li ng-repeat="value in data | filter: input.val" ng-class="{'active': $index == value.txt}  ng-click="input.val=value.txt">
                        {{value.txt}}
                  <hr ng-show="!$last" style="margin-top: -1px; margin-bottom: 12px;">
               </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
  .active{
        color:red;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you missing `''`

```
  ng-class="{'active': $index == input.val}
```

Comment: but I need to append this class to li elements on filtering

Comment: what do you want filter? odd or even or some thing? can you explain clearly @bpinky

Comment: it is a autocomplete filter,on filtering I need to append the active class for the list element

Comment: I think this fidde can help you , if not can you create fiddle file? http://jsfiddle.net/ja3h8/2/ @bpinky

Answer (score 0):

```
 <li ng-repeat="value in data | filter: input.val"   ng-class="{'active':value.txt.indexOf(input.val)>0}" ng-click="input.val=value.txt" >
                        {{value.txt}}
                  <hr ng-show="!$last" style="margin-top: -1px; margin-bottom: 12px;">
               </li>
```